# certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format

Tags: certificate, smime, nss, certificate-store, certutil

I had downloaded a verified (not self-signed) S/MIME certificate with iceweasel (firefox) which was stored in cert8.db

Then I used:

```
certutil -L -d <path_to_folder_that_cert8.db_resides>
```

in order to list the certificates, and then I extracted the .p12 file using the name of my certificate that certutil gave me:

```
pk12util -o mycertfile.p12 -n "<name_found_from_certutil>" -d <path_to_folder_that_cert8.db_resides>
```

The problem is that **I lost the access** to the PC that the p12 was stored and now I have only **a cert8.db copy** to another PC. Thus I repeated the `certutil && pk12util` commands, but certutil fails with:

```
certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format.
```

I have desperately tried at 3 different computers, including one with identical kernel and `libnss3-tools` version, (like the initial desktop where I extracted the p12 successfully) which is:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux commander 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-2 (2014-11-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`libnss3-tools` version: 2:3.17.2-1

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: After installing chromium and libnss3-tools, 'sql:${HOME}/.pki/nssdb' did not yet exist. I had to init the db via 'certutil -N -d sql:${HOME}/.pki/nssdb' first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is quite cryptic. I got similar error while using `certutil -L` to get the list of certificate in a `cert8.db` file.

Now I find why the command did not work.

The `–L` cannot work only with a `cert8.db` in a folder. It is also dependent on two other files, `key3.db and secmod.db`. 
So in a folder where all the above 3 files are present, `-L` works only there. 
And that’s why `–d` parameter takes a folder path. Not the `cert8.db` file.

I tried certutil by copying `cert8.db` from the Firefox profile folder to a temp directory.

I noticed it when certuitl -A succeeded but -L failed and the successful -A command created two other files in that temp folder.

Check also if the directory path have any space or not. With space, it gives the same error or 'bad file format error - old database format' etc. Specially in the Mac OS, the folder is in `"Application Support"` folder which contains space in the name. So it needs the path fully quoted:

```
"/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/jii912uh.default"
```

or add the \ escape character.

```
 /Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/jii912uh.default
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I know that `-dbdir` for `modutil` should also be the "directory where `secmod.db` is located", not one path ending with the filename.

Answer (score 26):

The database has migrated over the years from flat files to Berkeley DB to now SQLite in 3.12.  Prefix the directory name with `sql` and enclose in quotes to get around spaces:

```
certutil -L -d sql:${HOME}/.pki/nssdb
```

For reference, here's the [Mozilla NSS roadmap](http://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS:Roadmap#SQLite-Based_Shareable_Certificate_and_Key_Databases).

Comment: This did it for me, `-d .` gave the subject error but `-d sql:.` worked correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Oddly and confusingly, this error is also what you get if you're trying to query a certificate database in a location you don't have access to and you didn't use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to restore the whole .mozilla directory in order to run the certutil successfully. The file cert8.db needs to be in the original directory.

Comment: Check out the rest of the answers for a more sensible explanation